# detect multiple accounts

Tags: language-agnostic

I'd like to know what methods usually web applications employ in order to detect multiple accounts, supposing that the application wants its users to create a single account .

Answer (score 1):

Use the user's email address as his login (username). Store the email address as a unique key in your database. Not foolproof, of course. Then again, few things are. I'd avoid the temptation of using IP address. You'll get the same user logging in from multiple IP addresses if his ISP uses dynamic IP assignment. Conversely, many users can share a single globally-visible IP address.

Comment: but what if the users are carefully enough to delete all the cookies  before they attempt a second login at a different account ?

Comment: Agreed. Said user has defeated the scheme. What are the consequences of a user creating >1 account? I'm guessing they can go so far with a restricted, free account and a second account will give them twice the whatever. Hmmm... balancing the convenience of legitimate users with thwarting the cheats is the security person's stock and trade. Perhaps requiring a credit card number, though you'll lose something like 90% of your legit users. I'll think more about this...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the apps I've seen/written are based on a unique email address. If you've got more than one email address, you can apply for more than one account.

If it needs to be more complicated than that...I'd question why you want a user to have only one account.

Comment: As per my rant, below, I'm guessing that there is a financial consequence to allowing a user to have an infinite number of free accounts. Perhaps @rantravee can enlighten us further.

Comment: In this case allowing an user to poses more than an account would be equivelent to cheating, specially if the users can interact with each other. Of course one might think of a method to detect this, in the context of the application by analyzing user's behaviour, but is there a general solution/trick that could be applied to catch multiple accounts ?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and say you're talking about a browser based multi-player online game. That case is going to be hard to catch...and you're never going to get 100% coverage. If I knew a little more about the application, maybe I could suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ip Address is the most obvious sign that multiple accounts may be used. This is flawed if two people from the same IP have an account

Comment: Or you've got an entire company hidden behind a single NAT firewall.

Comment: Conversely, folks on AOL/dialup can get additional accounts simply by taking advantage of dynamic IP. Each sign-on brings with it a new IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented such a solution, but I think that you may use one or more of:

- Setting & checking a cookie
- Using sessions
- Storing the user IP
- Cross-referencing the details (address, city etc)

Answer (score 0):

Two people might share an IP, if they have several computers on a LAN, or their IPs are assigned dynamically. You can use a cookie to track the last username they logged in with. Then when they log in with a different name, you know the same browser's been used to access multiple accounts. You can use Flash's storage to get around them clearing their browser cookies.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases its simplest just not to care if a user has more than one account.  If its a situation where you are offering like x free per account and you want them to pay for extra your pretty limited.  If you have any uniquely identifiable that they can't lie about like address if they want you to send stuff to them you can disallow duplicates.  If its a really big problem I would add extra captcha or email validation steps if you detect a duplicate IP address.  That way you don't disallow a legitimate duplicate but you'll hopeful force moochers to just pay instead of going through the hoops.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of your suggestions will, IMHO, scare off a disproportionate number of legitimate users.

Comment: Granted additional hoops will clearly lose legitimate users but it then becomes a business decision of which is greater, the expected revenue from the lost legitimated users or the expected revenue from 'forced' to pay moochers.